# React native packager/bundler can't find private modules

Tags: react-native

I'mm trying to get react native to find modules outside the project folder, and it's working fine for most modules but it always trips when trying to find a module starting with @ ej: @mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl

This is my project structure

- project

  - apps

    - rn-cli.config
  - shared

    - components

And this is my rn-cli.config.js

```
const Path = require('path');
const blacklist = require('metro-bundler/src/blacklist')

module.exports = {
   extraNodeModules: {
    'react-native': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native'),
    react: Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
    axios: Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/axios'),
    redux: Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/redux'),
    moment: Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/moment'),
    'react-native-navigation': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-navigation'),
    'react-redux': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-redux'),
    'redux-thunk': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/redux-thunk'),
    'react-native-google-sign-in': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-google-sign-in'),
    'react-native-facebook-login': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-facebook-login'),
    'reactotron-react-native': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/reactotron-react-native'),
    'react-native-linear-gradient': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'),
    'lodash': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/lodash'),
    'react-native-communications': Path.resolve(__dirname,'node_modules/react-native-communications'),
    'react-native-vector-icons': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'),
    'react-native-fast-image': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-fast-image'),
    'react-native-share': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-share'),
    'react-native-fetch-blob': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob'),
    '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl': Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl')
},
getProjectRoots: () => [__dirname, Path.join(__dirname, '../../shared')],
};
```

Importing every other than @mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl works, this one results in the following error:

```
Unable to resolve module `@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl` from `/Users/jose/Desktop/townapps/shared/components/mapPopup/index.tsx`: Module `@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl` does not exist in the Haste module map or in these directories:
  /Users/jose/Desktop/townapps/shared/node_modules/@mapbox
```